# AngularJS Material: Cannot get value of md-select

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-material

I've got a AngularJS Material Select:

```
       <md-input-container style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <label>Roll</label>
            <md-select id="acc-type" required="" ng-model="rolle">
                <md-option ng-selected="true" value="Tenant">Tenant</md-option>
                <md-option value="Lessor">Lessor</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

and I want to get the actual selected option. I tried it with

```
    var e = document.getElementById("acc-type");
    var selectedItem = e.value;
```

but all I receive is undefined. Is there any option to get the value of a `md-select` in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already defined `ng-model="rolle"` in your `md-select`, you can access it via `$scope.rolle`

Try:

```
var selectedItem = $scope.rolle
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know it.

Comment: Additionally, this is demonstrated in the demos on the documentation site: 1) https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select#selected-text 2) https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select#option-groups. Click the view source button to see the example code or click the button to open it in CodePen and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Its in angular Js and model is already assigned so try 
Try

```
 console.log($scope.rolle);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know it.